# what is the relation between server, socket and IO in express

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm very new to web design and I'm trying to use express with node.js.

In the following code:

```
var app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

What is the relation/difference between http, server and io here?

Comment: How about reading some documentation and coming back with specific questions? [`http`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http), [`server`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener), [`io`](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io#how-to-use)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually fairly simple:

1. `http` uses `app` to handle incoming HTTP requests. Express (app) is acting on [`request`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request) event. This event is used to handle HTTP requests.
2. `io` attaches itself to the [`connection`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connection) event of HTTP server. I believe it's implemented [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/index.js#L175). `connection` event is emited whenever a new TCP connection is established, thus it's a good fit for web sockets.